# How to catch custom SOAP Header localPart Request in Spring Boot

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, soap, soapheader

I have POJO class named **RequestSOAPHeader** for SOAP Header.

In the @Endpoint I am catching the header like below

```
@SoapHeader("{" + RequestSOAPHeader.AUTH_NS + "}RequestSOAPHeader")SoapHeaderElement auth
```

My problem is when I am trying to unmarshall my header in POJO class i am having the following error.

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: unexpected element (uri:"http://www.test.com/schema/common/v2_1", local:"RequestSOAPHeader"). Expected elements are <{http://www.test.com/schema/common/v2_1}requestSOAPHeader>
```

I am using the following method for unmarsahlling my header

```
 private RequestSOAPHeader getAuthentication(SoapHeaderElement header){
    RequestSOAPHeader authentication = null;
    try {

        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(RequestSOAPHeader.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
        authentication = (RequestSOAPHeader) unmarshaller.unmarshal(header.getSource());

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return authentication;
}
```

According to the error I have changed my header localPart name to **requestSOAPHeader** and it works fine.

```
@SoapHeader("{" + RequestSOAPHeader.AUTH_NS + "}requestSOAPHeader")SoapHeaderElement auth
```

But I want to use **RequestSOAPHeader** as localPart for header, not **requestSOAPHeader**

Comment: Did you have any class that `implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>` ?

Comment: No. I am not using any class which implements SOAPHandler<SOAPMessageContext>. I am using the mentioned method getAuthentication(SoapHeaderElement header) for unmarshalling the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have already found the solution.

Just add the following snippet `@annotation` value on top of the header class. Hope it helps

```
@XmlRootElement(namespace = "http://www.gooogle.com", name = "RequestSOAPHeader")
public class RequestSOAPHeader{
....
}
```